# Why do I get this "passing argument to parameter" error

Tags: c

I keep getting this error while trying to compile on Linux:

**Passing argument to parameter here**
**int    fgetc(FILE *);**

The code is supposed to count in a file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reduce your question to a [mcve]. Currently you have three calls to `fgetc`, and you haven't indicated which is failing. I strongly suspect it's `fgetc("/n")` - I don't know what you expect that to do. Perhaps you meant `if (fgetc(files) == '\n')`?

Comment: You have more problems: `(c = fgetc(files)) != EOF` While `fgetc` returns an `int`, you assign the value to a `char` and then compare it to `EOF`, which is of type `int` again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your question to leave only the relevant part of the code on top. In the future, please include the *line number* reported from the compiler and/or try to isolate the error. (Also, check the link from Jon Skeet!)

Comment: @Gerhardh if the program compiles but freezes when at the it's supposed to calculate the characters, words and lines by using the function **characters = countChar(files);
  words = countWords( files);  lines = countLines(files); do you know what could be wrong? I also removed   (c = fgetc(files)) != EOF** and made it into an **else**.

Comment: That sounds like it's a separate problem, to be asked in a separate post with a separate [mcve]. Stack Overflow is intended to address one problem per post.

Comment: I agree that this is a different question. But before you post a new one, please take a closer look at your `while(1)` loop....

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( fgetc("/n")) {
```

You are using `fgetc` with a wrong parameter, the parameter should be a pointer to a `FILE` object that identifies an input stream (in your case it seems to be `files`)

Comment: if the program compiles but freezes when at the it's supposed to calculate the characters, words and lines by using the function **characters = countChar(files);
  words = countWords( files);  lines = countLines(files); do you know what could be wrong? I also removed   (c = fgetc(files)) != EOF** and made it into an **else**.

Answer (score 1):

The function `fgetc()` should have a paramater which is a `pointer to a FILE`. In your case, it should be `files` from your line

```
int countLines(FILE *files) {
```

So your code for comparing if the character read is a new line

```
if ( fgetc("/n") ) {
```

should be

```
if ( fgetc(files) == "\n" ) {
```